# Are the solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ linearly independent or dependent?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The quesion asks :

Let $P,Q$ be continuous real valued functions defined on $[-1,1]$ and $u_1:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R},i=1,2$ be solutions of the ODE:- $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+P(x)\frac{du}{dx}+Q(x)u=0,$$
$x\in [-1,1]$ satisfying $u_1(0)=0,u_2(0)=0$. Let $w$ be the wronskian of $u_1$ and $u_2$. then

(1) $u_1$  and $u_2$ are Linearly independent

(2) $u_1$  and $u_2$ are Linearly dependent

(3) $w(x)=0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$

(4)$w(x)\neq 0$  for some $x\in [-1,1]$

I am not getting how to conclude the options. Here i just know $u_1,u_2$ are any two solution and satisfying same initial condition. How can I conclude about it wronskian without knowing whether the solutions are linearly independent or not.

If two solutions satisfies the same intial conditions, can we say they are linear dependent..?then option 2 and 3 will be the correct one....

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

We have the following formula for Wronskian determinant (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) for example):
$$
W(x) = W(x_0) e^{-\int_{x_0}^x P(s)ds}.
$$
Since $u_1(0)=u_2(0)=0$, we find that $W(x) = W(0) = 0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$ and therefore $u_1$, $u_2$ are linearly dependent.